# javascript click() function doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

The next code works fine in all the browsers, except Safari. Why?

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('click').click();">
<a id="click" class="fancybox" href="#select">click</a>
<div id="select">Welcome!</div>
```

This code implies jquery. Maybe this is the problem ? Why it doesn't work in Safari ?

The next variant also doesn't work:

```
<a id="click" class="fancybox" href="#select" onmouseover="this.click();">
```

unless I click with the mouse (not on mouse over, as it should). So the problem is with click() function (just in Safari). What can I do ?

**SOLVED:**

Just must be added this function:

```
<script>
function autoclick(id) {
var a = $(id)[0];
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
a.dispatchEvent(evObj); }
</script>
```

And then, it can be called like this:

```
<body onload="autoclick('#click')">
<a id="click" class="fancybox" href="#select">click</a>
<div id="select">Welcome!</div>
```

or, another example:

```
<a id="click" class="fancybox" href="#select" onmouseover="autoclick('#click')">
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Nothing in your code implies jQuery - anyway it is a duplicate for sure http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+safari+click

Comment: @Marius please check my answer, jQuery will help you supporting event handlers using a single code on all browsers.